# "Call not sent" toast shows, but call goes through

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, toast, phone-call

I am using the Ionic framework to build my mobile app and when using the CallNumber module I keep getting a toast that says "Call not sent." on android and I suspect also for ios, however the call does go through every time and it is using the correct the phone number. Here is a short code snippet that shows what I am doing using the CallNumber module and Google Maps API. This is the documentation for the module: github.com/rohfosho/CordovaCallNumberPlugin

map.ts:

```
constructor(private navCtrl: NavController, private platform: Platform, private geolocation: Geolocation,
    private callNumber: CallNumber, private toast: Toast) {
  }

let prompt = {
          title: place.name,
          address: place.formatted_address,
          phone: place.formatted_phone_number,
          open_closed: (place.opening_hours.open_now ? "Open": "Closed"),
          opening_closing_time: (place.opening_hours.open_now ? "Closes " + time: "Opens " + time + daysOfTheWeek[day]),
          distance: distance
        };
       scopeObj.places.push(prompt);
       scopeObj.infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
         maxWidth: 250
       });
       marker.addListener('click', function() {
 document.getElementById("phone").addEventListener("click", function() {
             for (var i = 0; i < scopeObj.places.length; i++) {
               if (scopeObj.infoWindow.content.includes(scopeObj.places[i].address)) {
                 scopeObj.toast.show(`Sending Call`, '2000', 'center');
                 scopeObj.callNumber.callNumber(scopeObj.places[i].phone, true);
                 break;
               }
             }
           });
```

Comment: I wonder if you added the <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
 on the AndroidManifest.xml ...

Comment: Since I'm using the ionic framework to build the hybrid app, it adds permissions for android and ios when it builds the app for the platform, after I had installed the module to the framework, which I did.

Comment: So I am still unsure why it shows the toast, does someone knows how to fix that with the CallNumber module in Ionic?

Comment: Can I look at the whole of your `map.ts`? I want to see where the toast showing "Call not sent" is at.

Comment: The only toast that I created is the one that says "Sending Call", I did not make one for "Call not sent", it seems to be a predefined piece of code in the cordova module, CallNumber, so I can't explicitly effect it and I tried looking at the native code for the module and did not find the toast in Android. I believe that I found a bug in the module, but I am not sure how I can fix it. I can try asking the support center at Ionic.

Comment: This is the documentation for the module, if you want to look at it. https://github.com/rohfosho/CordovaCallNumberPlugin

Comment: The toast does not seem to show up anymore, it must have been temporary.